# export from lyx the right LaTeX class declaration

Tags: lyx, document-classes, export

I am using svjour3 class from Springer, but for convenience I decided to use the Lyx templates. 
Everything went smoothly and I managed to get all the layouts and formatting as required.

However, I need to submit for publication in TeX format. When I export LaTex(plain) I get

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{svjour3}
```

The expected output is

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
```

Obviously, I can change that manually after export, but I am wondering if there is anything that I can do at the lyx configuration level so that it exports directly in the expected form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some steps you can try, by modifying some things under Document --> Settings.

- `smallextended` can be added under *Document Class*: Add `smallextended` to the *Custom* class options.
- For the font size, look under *Fonts*. If *Base size* (see top right) is set to `12pt`, change it to *Default*.
- To remove `english` I think you need to go to *Language* and set *Language package* to *None*. Note that this will also remove `babel` from the packages, so you may not want to do so.